# Reload embed with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flash, embed

Hi to every one I want to how I can reload a flash embed ,

I try to reload with the follow code:

```
    function reload()
   {
    if (timerID)
    {
        clearTimeout(timerID);
    }

    tmp = findSWF("chart");
    x = tmp.reload("data.php");

    timerID = setTimeout("reload()", 3000);
}


function findSWF(movieName) {
if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!= -1) {
//return window["ie_" + movieName];
return document.getElementById('ie_'+movieName);
} else {
//return document[movieName];
return document.getElementById(movieName);
}
}
```

But the i get the follow js error:

tmp.reload is not a function

some know how to fix it, or if Im doing it rigth?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

you could just call a $.ajax or $.get function to replace the flash embed, put the flash embed in a container and user .innerHTML

for example:

```
if($.get("reload.php", {  },
      function (response){
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = response;
      })) {
} else {
alert ("Something's Wrong!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an unclosed string!

```
x = tmp.reload("data.php"); ?>");
```

is the erroneous line.

Fix that and it should recognize your function.